# Разбор верстки в переменные

Tags: php

Понадобилось для парсера разобрать вот такую верстку:

```
   <p dir="ltr"><strong>Количество комнат:</strong> 2</p>

<p dir="ltr">
    1-3 суток — 6300 руб./сутки<br>
    4-9 суток — 6300 руб./сутки<br>
    10-29 суток — 6300 руб./сутки<br>
    от 30 суток — 6300 руб./сутки
    </p>
```

Необходимо найти среди тегов p, эти два и вытащить значение к-ва комнат и оплату за 1-3 суток.

Сам попытался, ничего работающего не получилось. Подскажите, как лучше это сделать.

Answer (score 2):

```
$text = "text";
preg_match("/\<p dir\=\"ltr\"\>(.*?)\<br\>/is",$text,$temp);
echo $temp[1];
```

Comment: Не работает, я делал похожий вариант, но почти всегда элемент идет с другим классом, или вообще без него. Может покажете как сделать поиск по "руб./сутки"